# ZF2 Postgres query many to many

Tags: database, zend-framework2

I tried to search about this, but I can't formulate my question on google. Maybe has some term that I don't know.

I have two tables, one for clients and another for phone numbers. Each client could has many phones numbers. For each client, I wanna add the phones numbers associated with him. So what I did looks like:

```
$clients = $this->select();
$result = array();
foreach ($clients as $key => $client) {
    $client->phones = $this->getClientPhones($client->cli_id);
    $result[$key] = $client;
}
```

This works. But I wanna know if this is the right way to do it, if there is a best way.

Thanks.

Comment: I would go with a JOIN query. Place a client id in you phone's table and write a join query. Right now this is not very efficient, because of the large amount of queries it can produce in that foreach statement.

Comment: Hi @Stanimir, thanks for your reply. When I use JOIN in postgres, if a client has more than one phone number, then the row of the client repeat as many phones number I have in the table phones associated with the client. What if as long I loop through the clients, I wanna list the phones associated with the client?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this approach is that you're basically harassing your database with many queries. You're basically asking for the list of clients, then the list of phone numbers for client 1, then the list of phone numbers for client 2, then the list of phone numbers for client 3, etc.

A better approach would be to ask the database once to retrieve the client list and once again to get the list of phone numbers for all retrieved clients.

```
$clients = $this->select();
$clientIds = array_map(function($client){ return $client->cli_id; }, $clients);
$clientPhones = $this->getAllClientPhones($clientIds);
// do something with phone numbers
```

In sql, the `getAllClientPhones` works quite like `getClientPhones` but uses `WHERE client_id IN (?)` instead of `WHERE client_id = ?`.